# unable to execute the servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

below is the code i have made. its a login form validation using database.i called this servlet from a jsp page( that is when i click on the submit button of the login page it is directed to this servlet). but when i run it loads and only displays a blank page.can anybody tell me whats wrong.

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                    out.println("<html>");
                    out.println("<head>");
                    out.println("<title>check</title>");
                    out.println("</head>");
                    out.println("<body>");
                    out.println("<h2>check</h2>");
                    out.println("</body>");
                    out.println("</html>");
        String name=request.getParameter("username");
        String pass=request.getParameter("password");

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        Connection con;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:BusPassDS");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM logTab");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String dbName=rs.getString("username");
            String dbPass=rs.getString("password");
            if((dbName.equals(name))&&(dbPass.equals(pass)))
            {
                RequestDispatcher dis=request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp");
                dis.forward(request,response);
            }
            else
            {


                    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                    out.println("<html>");
                    out.println("<head>");
                    out.println("<title>Login Error</title>");
                    out.println("</head>");
                    out.println("<body>");
                    out.println("<h2>invalid username or password</h2>");
                    out.println("</body>");
                    out.println("</html>");



            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ValidationServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any strack trace or is your db connection  active check that try adding some sys O statements in  between i suggest at the start of dopost function with we can see that if the function is entering loop and one more doubt since you are using form did you set method attribute post or get

Comment: @user3127499 no there are no stack traces.

Comment: Did you check  jsp page side where the forms method attribute is set you are writing code in doGet so method should be get see if it is post attribute set and last add a try catch block e.printStackTrace()

Comment: @user3127499 n yes i have set the method to post and i have given the form action as the name of the servlet

Answer (score 0):

If the output is blank, then an exception must have been thrown.  The `out.println()` calls probably never made it to the client since they weren't flushed.

To debug this problem, try adding an `out.println()` to the `catch` block.  Also try putting some `out.flush()` calls within the `try` block.

Comment: i have added both. this is the catch code 'catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<p> error <p>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
            Logger.getLogger(ValidationServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }'

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the submit button, it `POST`s, not `GET`s. You servlet method is `doGet()`. Try putting something into the `doPost()`.

Comment: Exactly that was what i was talking about

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the content of your code in doGet to doPost it should work or else set form method="get" but in case of password validation post is better and write your code for validation in doPost

Comment: ok. i ve changed the method in the jsp to GET. and now it prints the "check" but inspite of giving the right name and password it does not direct to the success page neither to the error msg for wrong one. it just keeps loading.

Comment: just add sys o inside the password checking loop